# What is the best way to made multiple sync ajax request

Tags: ajax, angular, rest, browser, request

I convert xlsx to json and send the lines to backend trought ajax request.

The excel has 5k rows, I performed the requests using concatMap. There is another way to do this ? I readed the browsers has a maximium the 6~12 connections per host name.

When I tested this solution, it performed all requests in 6 minutes using 10 requests per time.

The browser really had 6 max connection per host ?

Anybody already made the same solution ?

--

Above there is a example of my solution

```
let ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let arrIds = this.chunkArray(ids, 3);

for(let i = 0; i < arrIds.length; i++) {
  this.getSomethingFromAnAPI(arrIds[i]).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response.name)
      this.data.push({
        body: response.name, 
        title: response.name, 
        id: response.id
      });
    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
 }

//Send line to api
public getSomethingFromAnAPI(ids: number[]): any {
      return from(ids).pipe(
        concatMap(id => <Observable<any>> this.http.post('SEND_LINE_API'))
      ); 
  }
```

Comment: If order doesn't matter for you then you can use ```switchMap``` instead of concatMap

Comment: @SiddharthPal when I used switchMap, the browser made 5k requests at the same time and cancelled a lot of them.

Comment: sorry my bad... my intention was to use ```mergeMap``` instead of ```concatMap```

Comment: Did you tried pushing your calls into an Observable<any>[] and after that calling forkJoin ?

Comment: Yes, i tried with forkJoin and mergeMap, but in the both cases the browser made all the 5k requests at the same time.... I need to implement a throttle system :(